# Как исправить ошибку “недопустимый else без парного if”?

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"     
#include <iostream> 
#include <math.h> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <iomanip> 

using namespace std;    

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(0, "Russian");
    double expr1, expr2, func, pi = 3.14;

    expr1 =pow(cos(fabs(sin(2 / pi))),4) / pow((1 + log(10)), 1 / 3) + pow(1.01, 10)*exp(cos(pow(2, 1 / 5)) + pow(7, 1 / 7));
    expr2 = log2(pi) + exp(pi) / sqrt(1 + pow(3, 1 / 3)) + asin(1 / 3);
    if (fabs(expr2)) + (fabs(expr1) >= 10);
    {
        func = log2(fabs(1 + expr2 + expr1) + 5 * pow(expr1, 1 / 3));
    }   
    else    
    {
        func = sin((pow(expr2, 2)) + pow(expr1, 2)) + pow(expr2, 10);
    }
    cout << "func=" << func << endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Неужели Visual Studio не обеспечивает подсветки парных скобок?

Answer (score 9):

Ты запутался в скобках и в точках с запятыми:

```
if (fabs(expr2) + (fabs(expr1) >= 10))
```

Answer (score 5):

Добавлю к ответу @Vladimir, что это у вас не единственная ошибка. В выражениях типа 1/3, 1/5 - вы используете целочисленные константы, а значит, и сами результаты выражения будут целочисленные. Не удивляйтесь потом, что `pow(2,1/5)` даст 1... Используйте литералы с плавающей точкой - типа `pow(2,1.0/5.0)`...